# Updating an image in tkinter from a listbox selection

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a program which populates 7 text boxes with information from a text file. The first linelist of the text file is a png which I need to display with the corresponding information.

The program functions so far and I have an initial image displayed at the top. But I am having issues implementing the code I need to update the image with the rest of the information.

From what info I have the part I need to implement is the three lines below, I just can't figure out why it isn't functioning with the rest of the program it either tells me logo is not defined or it completely breaks the program and gives no error.

```
logo.append(tk.PhotoImage(file="images/"+ lineList[0]))

lab8.configure(image=logo[len(logo)-1])

lab8.image= logo[len(logo)-1]
```

Rest of the program:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("300x600")

window.title("Realtor INC.")

##

def displayItem(event):

     line=lst1.get(lst1.curselection())

     lineList=line.split(':')

     txt1.delete(1.0,tk.END)

     txt1.insert(tk.END,lineList[0])

     txt2.delete(1.0,tk.END)

     txt2.insert(tk.END,lineList[1])

     txt3.delete(1.0,tk.END)

     txt3.insert(tk.END,lineList[2])

     txt4.delete(1.0,tk.END)

     txt4.insert(tk.END,lineList[3])



     txt5.delete(1.0,tk.END)

     txt5.insert(tk.END,lineList[4])



     txt6.delete(1.0,tk.END)

     txt6.insert(tk.END,lineList[5])



     txt7.delete(1.0,tk.END)

     txt7.insert(tk.END,lineList[6])

##logo

logo=[]

logo.append(tk.PhotoImage(file="logo.png"))

lab8=tk.Label(image=logo[0])

lab8.grid(column=0,row=0, columnspan=2)





txt1=tk.Text(width=20, height=1)

txt2=tk.Text(width=20, height=1)

txt3=tk.Text(width=20, height=1)

txt4=tk.Text(width=20, height=1)

txt5=tk.Text(width=20, height=1)

txt6=tk.Text(width=20, height=1)

txt7=tk.Text(width=20, height=1)





lab1=tk.Label(text="House Image Name")

lab2=tk.Label(text="Price")

lab3=tk.Label(text="Number of Bedrooms")

lab4=tk.Label(text="Number of Bathrooms")

lab5=tk.Label(text="Location")

lab6=tk.Label(text="Square Feet")

lab7=tk.Label(text="Availability")



lst1=tk.Listbox(height=10, width=40)



lab1.grid(column=0, row=1), txt1.grid(column=1, row=1)

lab2.grid(column=0, row=2), txt2.grid(column=1, row=2)

lab3.grid(column=0, row=3), txt3.grid(column=1, row=3)

lab4.grid(column=0, row=4), txt4.grid(column=1, row=4)

lab5.grid(column=0, row=5), txt5.grid(column=1, row=5)

lab6.grid(column=0, row=6), txt6.grid(column=1, row=6)

lab7.grid(column=0, row=7), txt7.grid(column=1, row=7)



lst1.grid(column=0, row=10, columnspan=2)



infile = open("houses.txt", 'r')



for line in infile:

     ##print(line, end="")

     lst1.insert(tk.END, line)

infile.close()

lst1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", displayItem)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works for me as expected. There is no need to use `logo.append(...`, change to `image = tk.PhotoImage(file="image/" + lineList[0])`

Comment: I assume I still need the other two lines for it to work? Also does it matter where in the code Im puting this. I have it right after the existing logo code, but it still isnt changing the image.

Comment: *"does it matter where in the code Im puting this"*: **YES**, must be inside of `def displayItem`

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure it out! I appreciate your help. I was putting the code to change the image with the initial 4 lines but I see now that it needs to be in the function to work with the linelist.